# Как добавить новую строчку в DataFrame при указании значения только одного столбца?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Необходимо добавить в DF новую строку, указав значение только одного столбца. Например имеем фрейм данных:

```
d = {'name': ['rick, mike, morty', 'tot, piter, carl', 'brick, nick', 'rick, reaven, bart, homer', 'rick, morty'],
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'],
     'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Необходимо добавить строку в конец фрейма, указав только значение адреса. Должно получиться следующее:

```
d1 = {'name': ['rick, mike, morty', 'tot, piter, carl', 'brick, nick', 'rick, reaven, bart, homer', 'rick, morty', 'Nan'],
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009', 'Nan'],
     'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY', 'VR']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1)
```

Причём, желательно обойтись без перебора функцией for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

```
df.loc[len(df)] = [np.nan, np.nan, 'VR']
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
df = df.append(dict(Address="VR"), ignore_index=True)
```

**Вариант 3:**

```
df = df.append(pd.Series("VR", name=len(df), index=["Address"]))
```

Answer (score 3):

в дополнение к уже предложенному:

```
df.loc[len(df),'Address'] = 'VR'
```

Comment: по-моему, это оптимальный вариант для случая когда отсутствуют данные для других столбцов )

Comment: Но это только если индексы строго от `0` до `len(df)-1`, а если вдруг в индексах разброд и шатание (например, из датафрейма что-то удаляли, а индекс не сбросили), то значение может попасть в уже имеющуюся строку. Как вариант можно взять индекс `df.index.max()+1`.

Comment: @CrazyElf, с "кастомными" индексами все еще веселее - они могут быть строками или timestamp, тогда и ваш вариант (`df.index.max()+1`) неправильно отработает )

Comment: @MaxU Безусловно. Но вариант "из датафрейма удалили (не выбрали) некоторые строки" всё-таки более вероятен )